# Task Manager always crashes within 1 or 2 seconds. Solutions?

Tags: windows-7, windows, crash, task-manager

This is the error report:

```
Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH  
Application Name: taskmgr.exe  
Application Version: 6.1.7600.16385  
Application Timestamp: 4a5bc3ee  
Fault Module Name: hostv32.dll  
Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0  
Fault Module Timestamp: 4c5c027d  
Exception Code: c0000005  
Exception Offset: 0000000000068b73  
OS Version: 6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.48  
Locale ID: 1033  
Additional Information 1: bf4f  
Additional Information 2: bf4f79e8ecbde38b818b2c0e2771a379  
Additional Information 3: d246  
Additional Information 4: d2464c78aa97e6b203cd0fca121f9a58  

Read our privacy statement online:  
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409  

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our 
privacy statement offline: 
C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Whenever I open the task manager, within a few seconds it crashes, saying it has stopped working with the above report.  I took the fault module (hostv32.dll) and scanned it with avast but it found no threat.  Any reason/solution to this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Run `SFC /scannow` from an elevated command prompt. This will scan all of the system files and restore them to their original versions if anything has been modified. If the task manager executable, or anything it depends on, has been damaged, it will fix it. For more details, see [KB929833](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833).